# JovoFramework - LAUNCH - isNewUser() is always false on AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, jovo-framework

I'm using jovo framework (version 1.0.0) and I'm facing the following problem:

In app.js:

```
app.setHandler({

  'LAUNCH': function() {
    if(this.user().isNewUser()) {
      this.tell('This will never be told on AWS Lambda.');
    }
  }
});
```

Running locally I can distinguish between (isNewUser === true) and (isNewUser === false) but as soon as I'm executing it as a lambda function on AWS isNewUser is always false. Why is that?

and additionally

```
NEW_USER': function() {
}
```

Isn't triggered either.

System Environment on local machine:

- Windows 10 Home
- NodeJS: v8.9.1

Lambda function:

- NodeJS 6.10

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `'NEW_USER'` and `this.user().isNewUser()` need to have access to a database, where the number of sessions is stored for each user.

When you're prototyping locally, it uses the default [File Persistence](https://www.jovo.tech/framework/docs/databases#filepersistence) database integration, which saves the data to a local `db/db.json` file.

However, on AWS Lambda, the local db doesn't work, so you need to set up a DynamoDB configuration. Learn more here: [Jovo Framework Docs > Database Integrations > DynamoDB](https://www.jovo.tech/framework/docs/databases#dynamodb).

Please remember to give your Lambda function role the right permission to access DynamoDB data: [AWS Lambda Permissions Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html).